# Slow nuget vs2017 install packages android

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget, visual-studio-2017

During the adding and removing of nuget packages, I have been experiencing extremely slow performance around the process in VS2017.  It can take upwards of 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the aapt.exe process was eating up all the resources even though it is not needed to add/remove the package.  To resolve this, when adding android packages - I open up and kill the process to allow the editor to quickly move along.  It is not graceful but does allow me to work quickly with no side effects.

[image]

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT - sorry, SO made me wait a few days before I could mark it an answer, & I forgot to return timely.